# How to get everything in the string, but a particular pattern

Tags: java, regex, scala

Yet another regexp question:

I have a string as the following,

`"This is a string, and I have a priority !1"`

So I want to build a regexp that extracts my priority, which is this number 1 preceded by the "!".
To extract it is very easy, "!([1-4])". But now I want to extract the text, leaving it out! How can I do that?

**DETAIL**: The !1 can be anywhere in the string, so this is also perfectly fine:

`"This is a string, !1 and I have a priority"`

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I'm using scala

Answer (score 3):

```
(.*?)!([1-4])(.*?)
```

This regex uses [lazy quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for better performance and will give you three capture groups:

- The text before the !1 marker (actually, the text before the first occurrence of the marker in the string).
- The marker itself
- The text following the marker

You can also use something like [String.replace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [Matcher.appendReplacement()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) as jarnbjo mentions in his answer, but in any case, these three groups give you what you need.

**EDIT:** Here is a correct version of the regex:

```
(.*?)!([1-4])(.*)
```

Based on the comments, I made the second quantifier greedy so it matches the rest of the string.

Comment: I thought about this also, but then I'll have to concatenate several groups after, because priority won't be the only embedded pattern..

Comment: if you have several embedded patterned, you can remove them with replaceAll as jarnbjo pointed out, but if you also need to find and analyze those patterns, then you already have to scan the entire string at least once.

Comment: Why do you think lazy quantifiers make this regex more performant?  It seems to me they're just as likely to *reduce* performance.  Also, the second `(.*?)` will never match anything.  A lazy quantifier as the last thing in a regex never makes sense; it will **always** match the minimum allowable number of characters, which in this case is zero.

Comment: You are right that the last quatifier doesn't have to be lazy, but it will indeed match some text, and not only zero characters. The first quantifier is lazy to reduce the number of backtracking. If it was possessive it would have matched the entire string and only then backtracked to first the marker

Comment: I think you mean *greedy*, not *possessive*;  possessive quantifiers never give anything back.  And your second `(.*?)` will match zero characters *unless* something forces it to match more, like an anchor (`$`).  Java's `matches()` method implicitly anchors the match at both ends, but if you use `find()`, group #3 will always be empty.  So, depending on which method you use, the second `(.*?)` is either pointless or useless.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace !1, !2, !3 and !4 with the empty string:

`String newString = "some string with !1 and more text".replaceAll("![1-4]", "");`

Comment: I was looking for a clean and maintainable way to do that.. =D

Comment: What do you find unmaintanable?  If there were in a method and the first argument were externalized, this seems reasonable to me.  But I do not know all of your requirements.

Comment: @José You want the string, with everything but `!1`, don't you? The replace will do exactly that. It's not like strings were mutable and you somehow lost the original string.